# Javascript and jQuery conflict on seat chart plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [jQuery Seat Chart Plugin](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts) in my website.

It's an old website so it uses JavaScript but this plugin is in jQuery so I am getting an error on the following jQuery code

```
function recalculateTotal(sc) {
    var total = 0;

    //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
    sc.find('selected').each(function () {
        total += this.data().price;
    });

    return total;
}
```

The error in console I get is `Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function` which I am guessing conflict error with JavaScript and jQuery.

When I use following code

```
sc.find('selected').each(function () {
        total += jQuery(this).data().price;
    });
```

It throws following error `Uncaught TypeError: this._each is not a function` with 'prototype' javascript.

I have tried to create a new extended function, tried to change the javascript versions but I am not able to solve the error.

Comment: How can javascript as a language and a framework that uses javascript conflict? No, your issue lies elsewhere. Probably your reference to `this` is not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Have you linked a jQuery library to your site before loading the Jquery Seat Chart Plugin?

Comment: @urbz you are right there. `this` is not referencing to what i am expecting. I am passing the plugin reference of `sc` in the function, so it should reference to all plugins method via `this` but its not. What should i do there?

Comment: @Zorken17 Yes i have and the problem is with `this` referencing. Help me solving that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a Javascript library, it's not a different language so there is no conflict there.

I see you're using jQuery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) with `sc.find('selected')` so the issue must be there:

1. `find('selected')` will select elements with `selected` html tag, which I doubt is what you want. you should use `.selected` if you're selecting elements with that class. or `#selected` if you have 1 element with said `id`. more about [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
2. if you're trying to get you get [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) from a jQuery selected element `selected` you should do it like this `this.data("price")`
   if you're trying to get `seatCharts`'s `data()` make sure you used `.seatCharts({})` on your `sc` element or you won't have the `data()` function there

Comment: I am just using same as in the demo example. I just applied same in my project. But I am looking into all possibilities.

Comment: seems like the plugin defines its own `.find()` and `.data()`. I suggest you you trace your steps one by one. first try `console.log(sc.find('selected'))` before using `each` and see if it returns any seats/elements I bet the issue is there

Comment: that line is working fine.The demo of that project on my pc works fine but it causes problem in my project. So i am guessing some `javascript` conflict or version problem somewhere.